# Git global alias to remove local branches not on remote

Tags: git, macos, alias

I have this **bash** code, which prunes local branches that don't exist on the remote:

```
git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

I want to make it a **git global alias**, so I can run all the magic like this:

```
git cleanup
```

So far I'm trying this (but it's not working):

```
git config --global alias.cleanup "git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d"
```

It complains that "git" is not a command. I tried making the first git a `!git` but then it just lists all the options for `git config`, as if I have the whole alias command wrong.

**Note**

I know this is not too tricky with a bash alias, but I'd like to try make it a git alias, so that it runs as if it's a git command.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ git config --global alias.cleanup '!bash -c "git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | xargs git branch -d"'
```

Or, just open the file `~/.gitconfig` and add:

```
[alias]
    cleanup = !bash -c \"git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d\"
```

Then confirm:

```
$ git config --list| grep alias
alias.cleanup=!bash -c "git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d"
```

Comment: I tried, it makes the alias, but when I run it it says `error: unknown switch 'r'` and starts listing usages of `git fetch`

Comment: @Mirror318 I have updated the answer. Did you put '' instead of "" while using ! ?

Comment: Another error: git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk "{print $1}" | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk "{print $1}" | xargs git branch -d: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: I ran the `!bash -c` version, but it tried to delete everything, including every word from commit messages, such as `error: branch 'Merge' not found.`, `error: branch 'pull' not found.`, `error: branch 'request' not found.`, `error: branch '#85' not found.`, etc.

Comment: @Mirror318 I just fixed the alias. Fixing the command was not part of your query :)

Comment: Hmm yea it's a confusing one. If I just paste the command by itself in the terminal, it does everything perfectly, but running through git breaks it..

Comment: Hi @Mirror318, have you ever gotten it up and running? The version in the answer still tries to delete everything, including `*`, `d3c38b7`, etc.

Comment: Sorry @SaveliiZagurskii it was a long time ago. These days I just delete branches 1 by 1, but you could make a bash alias for that command instead of a git one, so you can just type `clean_git` or something to run that for you.